# Hitting spacebar does not autocomplete username on commenter notification

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies, autocomplete

I was trying to respond to a comment in the following question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169746/my-gravatar-is-a-swastika-generate-new-gravatar

I typed the **`@`** followed by **`da`** to indicate my response to OP, whose name was *`damage`*. I remember that if I press <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, the user name usually auto completed but it didn't do it today.

When I initially typed the username's initial characters, the name appeared on the top.

[image: Initial typing]

Hitting <kbd>spacebar</kbd> did not complete the username

[image: After hitting space bar]

Did I do something wrong or am I thinking wrong that <kbd>spacebar</kbd> would complete the name?

#### Browser:

I am using Google Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97 m on Windows 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't it a <kbd>tab</kbd> that does the auto-completion? At least, that works for me (Chrome + Ubuntu).